# Restore tennis court

Tags: outdoor, landscaping

I currently own a property in Edinburgh, UK with what used to be a tennis court. It is depicted here:

[image]

What would be the cheapest way to convert this back into a tennis court?

Comment: what is underneath the moss?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not looking for an answer along the lines of "jackhammer it all up and start over"?

Comment: @ratchetfreak concrete from the old tennis court. Approx 20 years old.

Comment: Have you tried playing on it as it is? If you can play on grass, why not on moss?  Surely the cheapest option would be to just put up a net.  Wouldn't do for regulation tournaments of course, but could be very charming if it's not too slippery.

Comment: Scrape off moss in a few places and have a look. If the surface isn't too rough then spray with a moss-killer, leave for a few weeks and power-hose off the rest. If it needs resurfacing then wither call a tarmac company(cheapest resurface, but not most tennis friendly). Also, you have a drainage issue.

Comment: @AllInOne the moss will cut-up immediately so it'll be slippery, inconsistent and 100% worth filming to laugh at later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Pressure-wash away the moss.
2. Assess the integrity of the concrete. If it's sound, carry on. If not, abandon the project as there's no "cheapest" way of restoring it.
3. Acid etch the concrete to make it completely clean for recoating.
4. Skim any divots with vinyl repair compound to make them flat.
5. Commission a court finisher to apply the appropriate court coating and paint the lines. Alternatively, roll or spray a suitable court paint yourself.

<sub>Disclaimer: I've never restored a tennis court, nor have I perfected the overhand serve. Or even tried. Either thing.</sub>

Comment: Good answer. But in my (quite limited) experience, large areas of concrete left to weather and grow "stuff" for a few years generally have quite a bit of cracking, heaving, etc. So after (1), (2) will very likely be "no good".

Comment: I have restored a fruit packing room after a fire the concrete had many divots from the fire. We removed what was left of the equipment and basically did as @isherwood said to do but since it was a food processing plant we had to seal the concrete to make the health inspector happy.+ note that room was probably larger than a tennis court at 125x 75'. But I am not sure of a court dimensions.

Comment: @manassehkatz You don't know until you look.  If the first 10 sq feet is bad you can stop.